# Why "local holonomy contained in $SU(n)$" is equivalent to "vanishing Ricci curvature"?

Tags: differential-geometry, holonomy

I found it on Calabi-Yau manifolds' wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold#Definitions) and can't figure out why is it true.

Comment: I found an answer for this question:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0702063.pdf
page 29, first paragraph.